# Is it right to use __sync_bool_compare_and_swap in multithreading environment?

Tags: c, multithreading

code is below:

```
...
__sync_add_and_fetch(&g_cur_mem, size);
size_t curr = g_cur_mem;
while ( true ) {
    size_t peak = g_peak_mem;
    if ( curr <= peak )
        break;
    if ( __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&g_peak_mem, peak, curr) )
        break;
}
...
```

g_cur_mem is global variable to be used to save total memory used, g_peak_mem is global variable to be used to save peak value of g_cur_mem.

These code are in alloc() function of memory allocator in multithreading environment.

My question is: Is it right to use __sync_bool_compare_and_swap like this in multithreading environment?

or

Is the code right logically in multithreading environment to get right peak value of g_cur_mem?

Comment: wherelse would you use an atomic primitive, if not in a multithreading environment?

Comment: @JensGustedt You can have shared memory between processes without multithreading. But I think it's a safe bet that the primary use case for most atomic operations offered to user space is multithreading.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, sure it might make sense, but not all implementations do even guarantee that atomic operations work between processes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I don't see where it makes sense, if not in a multithreading environment. But you could use the [Atomic Buildins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) since this is recommended for the [Sync Builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html):

> These functions are implemented in terms of the ‘__atomic’ builtins. They should not be used for new code which should use the ‘__atomic’ builtins instead.